# Marker of overlay does not change position when Map resize

Tags: openlayers-3

I have an issue. 
The marker (of Overlay object) does not change position when Map resize.
Do you know how to change position automatically when map resize?

Thanks

Comment: It's not an issue, it's exactly what you should expect. Should it change to which position?

Comment: No, I do not want it change position. Eg: Current position is Australia, in Sysney. When I resize Map, That location move to about 100 pixel, and it is at another place. I want it still at Sydney

Comment: Oh, I see, so edit your question (**it reads just the opposite**) and show some code.

Comment: I use this for example. http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/geolocation-orientation.html?q=geolocation. Hope you can understand it